# Best way to detect that shadow password file is in use

Tags: c, linux

On Linux, what is the best way to detect that the shadow password file is in use.

Here is one way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   struct passwd *p;

   if (!(p = getpwuid(0)))
   {
      printf("root user not in /etc/password\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   if (strcmp(p->pw_passwd, "x")) {
     printf("using shadow passwd\n");
   } else {
     printf("shadow passwd\n");
   }
   exit(0);
}
```

I don't particularly care for htat solution as it is not direct.

Is there something more direct?
Is there something that does not require reading the passwd file?

My preference is a solution that does not require root privilege.

Although a bit more complex than this, my purpose is to give the user an explicit error message about the state of security on their machine.  For instance, if the administrator chooses to run my application WITHOUT setuid root and they have shadow password installed, I want to give them an explicit error message that they have to choose one or the other.  They also have the option of choosing a different authentication scheme.

Comment: Obtaining the `struct passwd` using `getpwuid()` (or `getpwnam()` for arbitrary users based on user name), and checking the `pw_passwd` field, is the most sensible one. If the password is just `crypt()`ed, it is exactly 13 characters long, and the first two characters are letters `A-Za-z`, numbers `0-9`, or full stop or dash `./`. If it begins with a `$`, it is a publicly-visible but salted password. If is is `x`, the password is in a shadow file. If it begins with a '!', the account is locked. Otherwise the password is remotely stored (LDAP, AD, or similar; often `##username`).

Comment: Do you really expect to ever come across a system *not* using shadow passwords in 2014?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not check if shadow is in use, just whether the root account has a non-shadow password. Setting the password hash to `"x"` is merely a way to ensure that no password can match it; other characters also work (`"*"` is fairly common too). If it's done when shadow is in use, this is just as a precaution to prevent programs not aware of shadow from allowing login via a blank password; otherwise leaving the field blank would be just as good.

The way to check whether root is using shadow passwords is to call `getspnam("root")`. This will of course fail if you're not root; that's the whole point of shadow. And it doesn't necessarily tell you that shadow passwords exist for all users, though it would be unusual to mix shadow and non-shadow.

Why do you need to know whether shadow is in use, anyway? Perhaps there's a better way to do what you're trying to achieve.